# How can I specify "fit to page" when printing on the command line with lpr?

Tags: command-line, printing

I'm trying to print an image from the command line, using `lpr`, but it ends up printing 4 pages instead of just one. Is there a way to tell lpr to fit the image to the page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved using the `scaling` option:

```
lpr -o scaling=100 image.jpg
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work with lpr supplied by CUPS.

Answer (score 12):

Old thread, but the option `-o fit-to-page` works.

Comment: Note that as of CUPS 2.1, the legacy option `-o fitplot` ([CUPS 1.3](https://www.cups.org/documentation.php/doc-1.3/options.html)) still seems to work.

Comment: Doesn't work as of CUPS 2.3.0.